# BAML obfuscation

Tags: baml

Is there any tool / commercial obfuscator that can obfuscate BAML resources in WPF controls?
If not, its a tough time in terms of IP protection sicne hackers can easily peek into the BAML resource by using BAML to XAML converters.

Comment: Since original XAML file consists mostly of build-in types (i.e. you can't mangle type names), what kind of information you want to conceal?

Answer (score 1):

Herein lies the problem with .NET stuff: Claytons Open Source -- the open source you do when you're not doing open source.

This subject has been visited a bit elsewhere on the web:

- [Protecting my intellectual property/XAML](http://dotnet.org.za/rudi/archive/2008/06/17/protecting-my-intellectual-property-xaml.aspx)
- [Code Protection and Licensing of WPF Applications.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/038a0c6e-3c5d-4497-b678-2fa9317b524f/)
- [.net obfuscator {smartassembly}](http://www.smartassembly.com/)

The latter looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since you wrote your question, but I wanted to inform you that obfuscation of XAML and BAML code is now possible.

At Creatix we have today released the 1.0 version of CodeFort, an obfuscation tool which is able to obfuscate .NET, WPF and Silverlight assemblies, and even rename identifiers inside of XAML and BAML code. This makes it for the first time ever possible to obfuscate 100% of a WPF or Silverlight Application's types and members.

You can learn more about the obfuscator and download the CodeFort Freeware Edition at:
http://www.codefort.org

Best regards,
Christian

Answer (score 1):

[Eazfuscator.NET](http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net) performs intelligent XAML obfuscation, including careful processing of the most complex binding expressions, etc. You can read more about it [here](http://eazfuscator.blogspot.com/2012/10/xaml-renaming-for-wpf.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) obfuscates XAML (in Silverlight assemblies ) as well as BAML (in WPF assemblies) - it renames class/member references inside the XAML/BAML files. Plus it will strip all comments, newlines and whitespace in these files turning them into garbage to the human eye.